# ReactNative) Questions about calling a function that references data within the render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The program flows as follows:

Home.js => Add.js => Detail.js => Repeat...

1. **Home.js** lists the posts.
2. **Add.js** is a page for entering the data required for a post. Move through stack navigation from **Home.js**
3. **Detail.js** will take over the data entered in **Add.js** as a parameter, show you the information of the post to be completed, and press the **Done** button to move to **Home.js**.
4. **Home.js** contains posts that have been completed.

If a post is created, **eatObject** is assigned an object from **Detail.js**.

`Const { eatObject } = this.props.route?params || {};`

In **Home.js**, state has an array of objects **toEats**.
Add **eatObject** to the object list

`{Object.values(toEats).map(toEat =toEat.id toEat.idToEat key={toEat.id} {...toEat} deleteToEat={this._deleteToEat} />)}`

Currently, the **refresh** button updates the 'Home.js' list whenever a post is added. But I want the list of posts to be updated automatically whenever 'Home.js' is uploaded.
I tried to call '_pushToEat' in 'componentDidMount', but 'eatObject' exists in 'render' so it seems impossible to hand it over to parameters.
I want to automatically call '_pushTooEat' when the components of 'Home.js' are uploaded.

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import ToEat from "./ToEat"

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toEats:{}
  }
  render() {
    const { toEats } = this.state;
    const { eatObject } = this.props.route?.params || {};
    // error
    // if (eatObject) {    
    //   () => this._pushToEat(eatObject)
    // }

    return (
      <View>
        {Object.values(toEats).map(toEat => <ToEat key={toEat.id} {...toEat} deleteToEat={this._deleteToEat} />)}
        <Button title="refresh" onPress={()=>this._pushToEat(eatObject)}/> 
        <View>
          <Button title="Add" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Add")} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  _deleteToEat = () => {

  }
  _pushToEat = (eatObject) => {
    console.log("function call!")
    console.log(eatObject)
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const newToEatObject = eatObject
      const newState = {
        ...prevState,
        toEats: {
          ...prevState.toEats,
          ...newToEatObject
        }
      }
      return { ...newState };
    })
  }
}
```

**Detail.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import uuid from 'react-uuid'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { inputId } from '../src/reducers/infoReducer';

class Detail extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name, dosage, note } = this.props.route.params;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>name: {name}</Text>
                <Text>dosage: {dosage}</Text>
                <Text>note: {note}</Text>

                <Button
                    title="Done"
                    onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate(
                            "Home", {
                            eatObject: this._createToEat(uuid(), name, dosage)                
                        })
                    }
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
    _createToEat = (id, name, dosage) => {
        const ID = id
        inputId(id)
        const newToEatObject = {
            [ID]: {
                id: ID,
                name: name,
                dosage: dosage,
            }
        }
        return newToEatObject;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        state: state.infoReducer
    };
}
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        inputId: (id) => {
            dispatch(inputId(id));
        },
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Detail);
```

I want your advice.
Thank you

Comment: `eatObject` is destructured from a prop, why wouldn't it be available in literally *any* function within the component? Perhaps you need to actually use some of the react component lifecycle functions, like `componentDidUpdate`. Is the issue that the `Home` component doesn't "get back"  a "toEats" object from the end of the flow from the details component?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your answer. As I understand it, I would like to add the `eatObject` object from the detail component to the home component's `toEats`. It is currently possible to add manually through the `refresh` button. It works.
But I hope the addition will be done automatically when uploading home component.
I'm thinking it could be possible with componentDidMount. But if there is another way, I want to know it. If you need any information, please ask me.

Comment: Can you confirm, what is logged when you add `componentDidUpdate() { console.log(this.props.route?.params?. eatObject); }` to `Home` and you navigate through your flow and add something from the details page?

Comment: Nothing was printed out as a result of doing as you suggested. If you're curious about the elements of the object, I can show you the result of inserting the `console.log (eatObject)` into the _pushToEat
`4f51c6d-d56f-a604-b6df-3d76c74413: {id: "4f51c6d-d56f-a604-b6df-3d76c74413", name: "asd", dosage: 0}`

(In this case, _pushToEat called through the 'refresh' button.)

Comment: What navigation are you using? `react-navigation`?

Comment: I am using stack navigation